# How lambda expression in Java 8 enables functional programming?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, java-8, functional-interface

How lambda expressions in Java 8 enable functional programming?
Because lambda expression type is represented as interface and which is object-oriented class type.

How normal method call differs from lambda expression statement?

Answer (score 3):

In the Functional Programming world, **functions are objects too and can be treated as traditional objects.**

Lambdas itself are simply behaviours without name handles. If you write `x -> x + 1`, you just created a value that represents an incrementation (or a concatenation of two strings).

This option allows to not only compose classical objects together but also to compose behaviours/actions - which is critical for Functional Programming which utilizes declarative programming a lot - in order to be able to achieve this, you need to be able to pass a behaviour in some way.

But, **the presence of Lambda Expressions does not make any language functional** automatically - there is much more to it, e.g. Immutability, Algebraic Data Types, lack of side-effects, functors, data types... and so on.

---

So, the relation between a lambda and a method is somehow similar to a relation between an anonymous value and a class field.

Answer (score 3):

**Lambda does not enable functional programming. It allows you to process data in more functional style.**

Java is an OOP language, where *first-class citizens* **are objects, not functions**. Therefore, even when you declare a *lambda expression* you have to assign it to some *Functional Interface*, which as you said is an object oriented class type.

However, in Java 8 you can use a *lambda expression*, which is an anonymous function, **like a first-class citizen to process data in a functional style**. E.g. you can **pass an anonymous function as a method parameter**.

```
accounts.stream()
        .map(account -> account.getEmail())
        .filter(email -> email.endsWith("gmail.com"))
```

This is a valid Java 8 code, where you **pass as method arguments, not values, but functions.** Of course, under the hood these lambdas become instances of classes that implement functional interface `Function<Account,String>`, and `Predicate<String>` accordingly, but still it allows you to process data in more functional style than in old Java versions.

The whole idea of processing data in a functional style involves also *Streams, Functional Interfaces, and Method Reference*, so you should consider them all when you think about functional programming in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Lets imagine pure OOP without class fields, setters and getters.
only classes and methods...
and we got a pure functional programming.
As fact, OOP - extends Functional Programming by adding state.
State adds reusability, save the time, by storing input parameters, incoming from class constructor.